# How to get the heart beat parameters from MI band with the help of Web BLE. Can anyone help me with html code?

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth-lowenergy

1
I want to get the Heart Rate through BluetoothLe from my Mi Band 2. I tried to follow the example from Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy but I didn't succeed to write the value from Heart Rate. I think I miss something but I cannot realize what. It's the first time I am working with bluetooth and smart band. I wish you could help me. I do not know if for starting the Heart Rate sensor should I use as {0x01} byte.

So following the example I downloaded the BluetoothLeDemo app and I got from there BleWrapper BleDefinedUUIDs and BleNamesResolver. I have 2 buttons Scan and stop. I created a BleWrapper, called mBleWrapper to use it for starting scanning and stop scanning.
This is the HTML code we are following to get the GATT parameters.

```
<button id="read">Connect with BLE device</button>
<button id="start" disabled>Start</button>
<button id="stop" disabled>Stop</button>

<script>
  var deviceName = 'Mi Smart Band 5'
  var bleService = '0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
  var bleCharacteristic = '00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
  var bluetoothDeviceDetected
  var gattCharacteristic

  document.querySelector('#read').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (isWebBluetoothEnabled()) { read() }
  })

  document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (isWebBluetoothEnabled()) { start() }
  })

  document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (isWebBluetoothEnabled()) { stop() }
  })

  function isWebBluetoothEnabled() {
    if (!navigator.bluetooth) {
      console.log('Web Bluetooth API is not available in this browser!')
      return false
    }

    return true
  }

  function getDeviceInfo() {
    let options = {
      optionalServices: [bleService],
      filters: [
        { "name": deviceName }
      ]
    }

    console.log('Requesting any Bluetooth Device...')
    return navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(options).then(device => {
      bluetoothDeviceDetected = device
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Argh! ' + error)
    })
  }

  function read() {
    return (bluetoothDeviceDetected ? Promise.resolve() : getDeviceInfo())
    .then(connectGATT)
    .then(_ => {
      console.log('Reading UV Index...')
      return gattCharacteristic.readValue()
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Waiting to start reading: ' + error)
    })
  }

  function connectGATT() {
    if (bluetoothDeviceDetected.gatt.connected && gattCharacteristic) {
      return Promise.resolve()
    }

    return bluetoothDeviceDetected.gatt.connect()
    .then(server => {
      console.log('Getting GATT Service...')
      return server.getPrimaryService(bleService)
    })
    .then(service => {
      console.log('Getting GATT Characteristic...')
      return service.getCharacteristic(bleCharacteristic)
    })
    .then(characteristic => {
      gattCharacteristic = characteristic
      gattCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged',
          handleChangedValue)
      document.querySelector('#start').disabled = false
      document.querySelector('#stop').disabled = true
    })
  }

  function handleChangedValue(event) {
    let value = event.target.value.getUint8(0)
    var now = new Date()
    console.log('> ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds() + ' UV Index is ' + value)
  }

  function start() {
    gattCharacteristic.startNotifications()
    .then(_ => {
      console.log('Start reading...')
      document.querySelector('#start').disabled = true
      document.querySelector('#stop').disabled = false
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('[ERROR] Start: ' + error)
    })
  }

  function stop() {
    gattCharacteristic.stopNotifications()
    .then(_ => {
      console.log('Stop reading...')
      document.querySelector('#start').disabled = false
      document.querySelector('#stop').disabled = true
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('[ERROR] Stop: ' + error)
    })
  }
</script>
```

Please anyone help me to find the issue.